# Where is the source code for the ADB install command?

Tags: android, adb

I found the following source code linked to below, but I don't see any implementation. I would like to know what happens on the device side when install is called.

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/client/adb_install.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

int install_app(int argc, const char** argv);
int install_multiple_app(int argc, const char** argv);
int install_multi_package(int argc, const char** argv);
int uninstall_app(int argc, const char** argv);

int delete_device_file(const std::string& filename);
int delete_host_file(const std::string& filename);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of this header is located in the same directory, named [`adb_install.cpp`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/client/adb_install.cpp). Typically the name of an implementation file (`.c` / `.cpp`) matches the name of its corresponding header file (`.h`).